# refund virtual items in ios/android?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

I was wondering if there is some mobile API to allow someone who bought/earned some virtual items to refund? I know that Apple has a no refund policy and Google has some timeframe to manually perform a refund, but maybe there is some API to handle it in some other way?

Comment: Users can get a refund for in-app purchases if they contact Apple support.  The money is refunded but the purchase is not reversed from an in-app point of view (so effectively the app developer "loses").  There is no API for refunds

Comment: hmm, thanks, I actually found some alternative (relevant in my case), someone maybe familiar with VIXN? (vixn.mobi, not the unix text editor...), although I can't refund programatically using it, I can allow users to "recycle" their leftover virtual currency for some other things in another game, so at least their stuff doesn't "go to waste" when they are done with my app (and it also generates money cuz the other game pays me for that user...)